Spring 6 upgrade @PreAuthorize not working with ArgumentResolver
I'm doing some testing on a Spring 6 upgrade and when we promoted to an environment with a public access pattern, a PreAuthorize decorator is failing.

A user submits a form with a save request.
the /save endpoint has a @PreAuthorize decorator that uses a helper method, AuthorizationHelper.IS_STATUS_VALID
The endpoint also specifies an object in the method signature that is used in the PreAuthorize decorator, which is resolved with a custom ArgumentResolver. The code looks like this

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('IS_APPLICANT', 'IS_ADMIN') and " + AuthorizationHelper.IS_STATUS_VALID)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute SomeModel sm, WebRequest request,
            HttpSession session, AuthorizationDto authDto) {
          // do page logic
          return some page view;
     }

I have confirmed that the ArgumentResolver is correctly registered and that the authDto is correctly initialized. In this one environment, when the AuthorizationHelper isStatusValid method is invoked through what I believe is a Spring SpEl expression, the authDto is as null. I am new with this application and looking for some help on why that might happen. My research suggests it may be a problem with the environment configuration, but I want to know what I am looking for to fail. This is what the AuthorizationHelper code looks like.
@Component
public class AuthorizationHelper {
    // constructor
    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationHelper(){
     // init any services needed
    }

    public static final String IS_STATUS_VALID = "@authorizationHelper.isStatusValid(#authDto)";

    public boolean isStatusValid(AuthorizationDto authDto) {
        logger.info("AuthorizationHelper :: authDto: " + authDto); // is null
        // do logic
        return result;
    }

}

And for good measure, I will post the aurgement resolver code as well, although i have confirmed this is working.
@Component("authResolver")
public class CustomAuthorizationResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
        NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        AuthorizationDto authDto = new AuthorizationDto();
        // some logic
        logger.info("AuthorizationDto after setting properties: {}", authDto); // not null. is invoked when the /save endpoint is hit, before the PreAuthorize code is executed
        return authDto;
    }
}

Again, I will start digging into any environment configuration differences. The biggest one I'm aware of is this environment has a different access pattern than the dev environment. My initial research indicated it could be a proxy issue. I appreciate any help!
Here is the relevant snippet of the stack trace
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.example.app.dto.AuthorizationDto.doSomeValidation()" because "authDto" is null
at org.example.app.web.helpers.AuthorizationHelper.isStatusValid(AuthorizationHelper.java:49)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:142)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:125)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:401)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:97)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:222)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpAnd.getBooleanValue(OpAnd.java:57)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpAnd.getValueInternal(OpAnd.java:52)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:119)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:309)
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:30)
at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager.check(PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager.java:68)
at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager.check(PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager.java:40)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager.check(DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager.java:47)
at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:251)
at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:197)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.example.app.web.controllers.ApplicantController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.save(<generated>)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(D


To increase your chances to get a helpful answer, I recommend to link to a MCVE, ideally on GitHub and with two branches for the old and new Spring version. If other developers can easily reproduce your problem without creating a reproducer project from scratch (which is your job) and filling in the gaps left here, it is also much easier to help you.

I really don't know, but if I read https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder#1-custom-argument-resolver I would say, you didn't create a annotation, you didn't add it in your WebMvcConfigurer and you didn't implement supportsParameter. Maybe I'm wrong.

The issue was our new relic jar needed to be updated. It was incompatible with the other spring updates we did and we didn't use it in the lower environments.
